# I am trying to " translate" my old c++ code into c# code

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I am trying to " translate" my old c++ code into c# code as headlines would suggests.Problem was that i am new in c# and not all things are as in c++.In c++ works well these solutions,but in c# just cant.I will show you my old c++ code that is been working and c# code that "should be" working.If i use for loop,result are always 0(zero).Also when  i use (arrayname).Sum().I tried some other solution found online,but none of it works.Anyone of it either displays (zero) as a result or throws exception.Help!
Here's my c++ code as well c# where not all functions are avaliable because i been testing only first one.If it not works on first one,then will not work on others.

Here is my c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class BrojniNiz {
  decimal b;
  public static int i;
  public decimal[] broj = new decimal[i];
  public Decimal Unos_brojeva() {
    Console.WriteLine("Unesi broj clanova niza: ");
    decimal[] broj =
          new decimal[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];

    // odredjuje se tip niza,tj. tip promenljive koje ce biti primane u niz
    //    (ovo se odnosi na " broj ").

    Console.WriteLine("Unesi brojeve: ");

    for ( i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++) {
      // " i " je broj clanova niza(njegova " duzina "),tj. konacan indeks.
      broj[i] = (Convert.ToDecimal (Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Unos brojeva je zavrsen");
    return 0;
  }

  Decimal Aritmeticka_sredina() {
    // for (i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++)
    // b = broj[i];
    // b = b + broj[i];
    // b += broj[i];

    b  = broj.Sum();

    //  i++;
    //Console.WriteLine(i);

    Console.WriteLine(b);

    //Console.WriteLine(broj.Length);
    return 0;
  }

  public int Meni() {
    Console.WriteLine("Unesi broj operacije po zelji: \n ");
    int a =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (a) {
      case 1:
        Aritmeticka_sredina();
        break;
      case 2:
        // Harmonijska_sredina();
        break;
      case 3:
        // Geometrijska_sredina();
        break;
      case 4:
        // Kvadratna_sredina();
        break;
      default:
        Console.WriteLine("\nUneli ste pogresne parametre..._\a\a\a\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  static  int Main() {
    BrojniNiz brojka;
    brojka=new BrojniNiz();
    brojka.Unos_brojeva();
    brojka.Meni();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Here my c++ code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>
using namespace std;

class Racniz {
  public:
    Racniz();
    ~Racniz();
    string lozinka;
    float unos_brojeva();
    int Meni();
    float Aritmeticka_sredina();
    float Harmonijska_sredina();
    double Geometrijska_sredina();
    float Kvadratna_sredina();
    void Pauza();
  private:
    int a;
    float unos [30];
    int n;
    float A;
    float sumaA;
    float H;
    float sumaH;
    double sumaG;
    double stepen;
    double G;
    double n1;
    float sumaK;
    float medjusuma;
    float K;
  };

  int main() {
    Racniz racunanje;
    racunanje.unos_brojeva();
    racunanje.Meni();
    racunanje.Pauza();
  }

  Racniz::Racniz() {
    sndPlaySound("Crysis 2 menu music-theme.wav", SND_ASYNC);
    cout<<"Uneti sifru za rad u programu..._\n"<<endl;
    cin>>lozinka;
    if(lozinka=="struwellpeter") {
      cout<<"\nSada ce se startovati program za statisticke proracune:\n"<<endl;
    } else {
      cout<<"\nPogresili ste lozinku,program ce sada izaci..._\a\a\a\n"<<endl;
      exit (0);
    }
  }

  Racniz::~Racniz() {
    cout<<"Kraj izvrsenja proracuna..._\n"<<endl;
  }

  float Racniz::unos_brojeva() {
    cout<<"Unesi 30 brojeva:\n"<<endl;
    for(n=0;n<30;n++)
    cin>>unos[n];
    cout<<"\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }

  int Racniz::Meni() {
    cout<<"Unesi broj operacije po zelji: \n "<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------------\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Aritmeticka sredina: \n "<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Harmonijska sredina: \n "<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Geometrijska sredina: \n "<<endl;
    cout<<"4.Kvadratna sredina: \n "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    switch(a) {
      case 1:
        Aritmeticka_sredina();
        break;
      case 2:
        Harmonijska_sredina();
        break;
      case 3:
        Geometrijska_sredina();
        break;
      case 4:
        Kvadratna_sredina();
        break;
      default:
        cout<<"\nUneli ste pogresne parametre..._\a\a\a\n"<<endl;
        break;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  float Racniz::Aritmeticka_sredina(){
    float A=0;
    float sumaA=0;
     for(n=0;n<30;n++) 
       sumaA=sumaA + unos[n];
    A=sumaA/n;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"SumaA je = "<<sumaA<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Aritmeticka sredina je = "<<A<<"\n"<<endl;
    return 0;        
  }

  float Racniz::Harmonijska_sredina() {
    float H=0;
    float sumaH=0;
    for(n=0;n<30;n++)
    sumaH=sumaH + 1/unos[n];
    H=n/sumaH;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"SumaH je = "<<sumaH<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Harmonijska sredina je = "<<H<<"\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }

  double Racniz::Geometrijska_sredina() {
    //Interval od ~ -19.2 do ~ 19.2 ,da ne bi doslo do "overflow-a".
    double sumaG=unos[0];
    double stepen=0;
    double G=0;
    for(n=1;n<30;n++)
      sumaG=sumaG * unos[n];
    double n1=n;
    stepen=stepen+1/n1;
    G=pow(sumaG,stepen);
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"SumaG je = "<<sumaG<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Geometrijska sredina je = "<<G<<"\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }

  float Racniz::Kvadratna_sredina(){
    float sumaK=0;
    float medjusuma=0;
    float K=0;
    for(n=0;n<30;n++)
      sumaK=sumaK + pow(unos[n],2);
    medjusuma=medjusuma + sumaK/n;
    K=K + sqrt(medjusuma);
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"SumaK je = "<<sumaK<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Medjusuma je = "<<medjusuma<<"\n"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Kvadratna sredina je = "<<K<<"\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
  }

  void Racniz::Pauza(){
    system("pause");
  }
```

Thanks people from this forum for help.I succesfully translated c++ code into c#.Here it is:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



   class BrojniNiz
    {


       public static int i=0;
       public double[] broj = new double[i];



       public double Unos_brojeva()
       {

      Console.WriteLine("Unesi broj clanova niza: ");
      broj = new double[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];  // odredjuje se tip niza,tj. tip promenljive koje ce biti primane u niz(ovo se odnosi na " broj ").
      Console.WriteLine("Unesi brojeve: ");
            for ( i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++)  // " i " je broj clanova niza(njegova " duzina "),tj. konacan indeks.
            {
                broj[i] = (Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()));

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Unos brojeva je zavrsen");
            return 0;
           }


     double Aritmeticka_sredina()
       {

            double b = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++)
            b = (b + broj[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Rezultat je sledeci: " + (b/i));
            return 0;


       }

       double Harmonijska_sredina()
       {

          double H = 0;
          double sumaH = 0;
          for(i=0;i<broj.Length;i++)
          sumaH=sumaH + 1/broj[i];
          H=i/sumaH;
          Console.WriteLine("Rezultat je sledeci: " + H);
          return 0;


       }
       double Geometrijska_sredina()
       {  

           double sumaG = broj[0];
           double stepen = 0;
           double G = 0;
           for (i = 1; i < broj.Length; i++)
           sumaG = sumaG * broj[i];
           double n1 = i;
           stepen = stepen + 1 / n1;
           G = Math.Pow(sumaG, stepen);
           Console.WriteLine("Rezultat je sledeci: " + G);
           return 0;

       }

       double Kvadratna_sredina()
       {

         double sumaK = 0;
         double medjusuma = 0;
         double K = 0;
         for(i=0;i<broj.Length;i++)
         sumaK = sumaK + Math.Pow(broj[i], 2);
         medjusuma=medjusuma + sumaK/i;
         K=K + Math.Sqrt(medjusuma);
         Console.WriteLine("Rezultat je sledeci: " + K);
         return 0;

       }

     public int Meni()
       {

         Console.WriteLine("Unesi broj operacije po zelji: \n ");
         int a =Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         switch (a)
         {

             case 1:
                Aritmeticka_sredina();
                 break;
             case 2:
                  Harmonijska_sredina();
                 break;
             case 3:
                  Geometrijska_sredina();
                 break;
             case 4:
                  Kvadratna_sredina();
                 break;
             default:
                 Console.WriteLine("\nUneli ste pogresne parametre..._\a\a\a\n");
                 break;

         }
         return 0;
     }






      static  int Main()
        {

            BrojniNiz brojka;
            brojka=new BrojniNiz();
            brojka.Unos_brojeva();
            brojka.Meni();
            return 0;
           }

   }
```

Comment: why are you using decimals? they are for financial calculations mostly. Better use double.

Comment: Can you please turn this into a small sample? Have you debugged this yourself? What are your expected inputs/outputs etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `Unos_brojeva` function.  You are defining a new locally scoped variable named broj, rather than modifying the broj array you have defined for the `BrojniNiz` class.

So, replace

```
decimal[] broj = new decimal[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
```

with

```
broj = new decimal[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
```

Comment: Thanks brother.Thanks for the answer and patience.I deleted my previous comments trying to make precise questions but failed.English aint my native language.Youre answer solved a bit.I am novice to c# and thanks again for patience user2798869.Just to let you know i also edited function Aritmeticka_sredina :  Decimal Aritmeticka_sredina().Now works in c# as in my c++ code aka gives same results.
     {
         
         for (i = 0; i < broj.Length; i++)
            
            
   b = (b + broj[i]);
            
        
       
Console.WriteLine("Rezultat je sledeci: " + (b/i));
return 0;